# Android Development: Find every picture on SD?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get all let say pictures (*.jpg) and list them in a listview /adapter?
And find all pictures within subfolders too.

Thank you!
Regards user564612

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that... `MediaStore` does it for you.

What you'd need to do is query the MediaStore content provider, probably with [`MediaStore.Images.Media.query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#query%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: can i pick something else like .mp3 or .txt too?

Comment: For MP3, certainly. A content provider query is a database query... check the docs and you'll see the MediaStore content provider has a MIME_TYPE column. You could filter your query for "audio/mpeg".